# Why can components only return one node in ReactJS? (Is there a fundamental reason?)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

From the docs:

> **Maximum Number of JSX Root Nodes**
>
> Currently, in a component's render,
>   you can only return one node; if you have, say, a list of divs to
>   return, you must wrap your components within a div, span or any other
>   component.
>
> Don't forget that JSX compiles into regular js; returning two
>   functions doesn't really make syntactic sense. Likewise, don't put
>   more than one child in a ternary.

The explanation above says "currently," which suggests that a component that could potentially return a function that results in two nodes instead of one. Is this just a technical limitation, or is this baked into the philosophy?

How I thought of this question: I'm in a situation where I'm trying to render a Bootstrap menu using React, and Bootstrap uses child selectors, instead of descendent selectors, which makes perfect sense.

---

**Aside:** How I solved my particular problem:

I'm mostly interested in the architecture of React, but in case you're curious this was my situation.

Currently in Bootstrap you can make a dropdown menu:

```
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown pull-right">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true"> Menu <span class="caret"></span> </a>
    <div id="macroMenu" class="react-component">
        <ul class="macroInsertion dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control search-filter" placeholder="Search" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

The default Bootstrap stylesheet has selectors like .pull-right > .dropdown-menu and .open > .dropdown-menu though, which don't work if you insert a single element in between container and contained. This makes sense because it's presumably faster and Bootstrap may sometimes deal with double-nested selectors, but it broke our system to have .react-component in the middle.

In my case, I manually figured out what .react-component was breaking and made new styles to account for the missing behavior.

Comment: Can you expand on your use case? This would help in suggesting alternative. Right now I don't understand the point about Bootstrap and selectors.

Comment: Sure. I ended up solving the problem through an orthogonal solution, but I'm still interested in the philosophy of React which is why I worded the question the way I did.

Comment: Added an explanation - I already fixed the problem.

Comment: [Jordan's comment](https://twitter.com/jordwalke/status/553154691643613184)

Comment: interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a technical limitation currently.  However there has been some (casual) talk about allowing this:

```js
var Foo = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return [<Bar />, <Baz />];
  }
});

var Quux = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return <div><span /><Foo /></div>;
  }
});
```

And `<Quux />` would result in this structure:

```js
<div>
    <span />
    <Bar />
    <Baz />
</div>
```

This is useful to deal with some rigidity in HTML (tables, lists, head), and also for styling where siblings matter (e.g. `display: inline-block`) or where you have no control over the styling and direct child (`>`) or sibling selectors (`~` or `+`) are used.

If you do run into one of these cases, you're most likely just implementing render, so using a utility function instead of a component would be a good workaround.

```js
var Foo = function(props){
    return [<Bar />, <Baz />];
}

var Quux = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return <div>{flatten( <span />, Foo({}) )}</div>;
  }
});


// usually you get this from underscore or similar
var flatten = function(){ return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function(acc, x){ return acc.concat(x) }, []) };
```